# Does shiva stambha yoga also awaken the third eye?

Tags: shiva

Does practice of this particular pillar yoga awaken the third eye aswell if practiced alongside vegetarianism and ahimsa?

Comment: Is there a consensus on what is the third eye?

Comment: @Severus Snape ,the vijnana bhairava tantra,guru gita and shiva samhita talks about this.its an Awakened Ajna chakra by Deeksha by a self realized guru in most cases and with it you can perceive everything and also manifest reality the way you like it through the kalpataru Shaktih .shiva creates reality with his third eye and you are one with that power when you open up your third eye too through the kalpataru Shaktih .

Comment: Valmiki wrote the Ramayana by recollecting ramas story through his awakened third eye.

Comment: “you can perceive everything and also manifest reality the way you like it through the kalpataru Shaktih” wow..yoga as a tool then for power...what about considering devotion instead?

Comment: Because manifesting powers is the best thing after enlightenment.with power there are no obstacle to moksha.